# Binomial coefficient when the order is smallest to largest

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients

Let's say there are 11 places in a line where one *can* put boxes. How many options exist to place there 5 different sized boxes, when the order of the size is from smallest to largest?

The number of ways to choose k items (5) from n (11) distinct items, where the order of the items matters is: $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

But how can I adjust this number and consider only the orders that are strictly from smallest to largest? My idea was to just divide this number by $5!$. Is this valid?

Comment: Yes, the question is in fact equivalent to choosing $5$ places out of $11$ where order doesn't matter

Comment: Assuming the boxes have to be in different places, that division by $5!$ is correct and gives you the [*binomial coefficient*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and numbers form Pascal's triangle.  If they can be in the same places as each other, then division by $5!$ does not work

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dividing everything by k! will give you the number where the order has to be strictly from smallest to largest. As @Maximilian_Janisch said, the question is in fact equivalent to choosing 5 places out of 11 where order doesn't matter.

$\frac{n!}{ k! (n-k)!}$

Comment: Thank you very much!